# "symfony framework standard-edition" requires old version

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to install

"symfony/framework-standard-edition": "2.6.6",

however

> php composer.phar update

shows this error

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/framework-standard-edition[v2.6.6, 2.2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.6.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[v2.6.6].
```

why symfony framework standard-edition[2.6.6] requires standard-edition[2.2.x]??

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",


        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "2.2.*",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",


        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.4.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",

        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.5",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.3.6",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.0",

        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.1",
        "adesigns/calendar-bundle": "dev-master",

        "jms/payment-paypal-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/payment-core-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",

        "friendsofsymfony/message-bundle": "dev-master",

        "symfony/expression-language": "2.7.*@dev",
        "symfony/framework-standard-edition": "2.6.6",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.0"


    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `symfony/framework-standard-edition` should not be in your dependencies, you should remove it.

`symfony/framework-standard-edition` is a skeleton for a new Symfony project, only to be used when initially creating the project, eg. `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition`.

Comment: I really misundersood the basic thought of composer, great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
"dev-master": "2.2-dev"
```

with

```
"dev-master": "2.6-dev"
```